# Google Timeline - change color of data depending on name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, graph, charts, timeline

I have a google timeline as in the code below, and want to change the color of any of the entries that are title "BLACK".
I can't seem to get it to work, and I've tried a few different solutions. Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/5j0umkcx/1/

---

Html:

```
<div id='chart_div'></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myData = [
        ['Category', 'Name', {role: 'style'}, 'Start', 'End'],
        ['Foo', 'BLACK', '', new Date(2014, 7, 1), new Date(2014, 7, 5)],
        ['Foo', 'Homer', '', new Date(2014, 7, 6), new Date(2014, 7, 8)],
        ['Bar', 'Marge', '', new Date(2014, 7, 2), new Date(2014, 7, 9)]
    ]

        for(i=1;i<myData.length;i++){
    if(myData[i].Name == 'BLACK'){
        data[i].style = '#000000';
    }}


function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(myData);



    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        height: 300,
        width: 600
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['timeline'], callback: drawChart});
```

Comment: data in your if statement at the top will be `undefined`, because it is only ever declared in the function scope

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what to fix their sorry. Any chance you could alter the jsfiddle? (Also just noticed I called 'data', not 'myData' in the if statement). Changing that didn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn;t work because you haven't given it whatever package `google` comes from. If you look in the browser console you can see that `google is not defined`

Comment: The fiddle works - you might just have to give it a second to load. Google should work automatically in this - I've tested on multiple browsers and computers. Maybe try Chrome? (Though I understand if you don't wish to help, that's okay).

Comment: You are right, seems like my browser is blocking the extension. I'll try and get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are working with `arrays`, but you are treating them as `Objects`. `myData[i]` has no property of `Name`, because it is an `Array`. Though, you can access where the `Name` is, by getting `myData[i][1]` (The slot in the array in which the name is stored). You can replace your for loop code with this to change the colour attribute (`myData[i][2]`)

```
for(i=1;i<myData.length;i++){
    if(myData[i][1] == 'BLACK'){
        myData[i][2] = '#000000';
    }
}
```